# MySQL Workbench. How to have multiple conditions using LIKE, OR, AND

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Is there any way to split up the expressions using the Like,OR, and AND operators. I am trying to use parenthesis to split my expressions, but I either get "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" or "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value" errors.

I want to have my statement to be almost set up like this,

((statement LIKE (This or This)

AND statement LIKE This))

OR statement LIKE this

```
DELETE FROM ap.vendor_contacts 
WHERE
    ((last_name LIKE 'd%' OR '%s')
    AND first_name LIKE 'm%')
    OR first_name LIKE '%al%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Syntax error. You **cannot** use `LIKE` operator as: `<fieldname> LIKE <value1> OR <value2>`. It has to be as follows:

`<fieldname> LIKE <value1> OR <fieldname> LIKE <value2>`

Do the following instead:

```
DELETE FROM ap.vendor_contacts 
WHERE
    ((last_name LIKE 'd%' OR last_name LIKE '%s')
    AND first_name LIKE 'm%')
    OR first_name LIKE '%al%'
```

Comment: Can you not combine multiple OR's for one LIKE? Would the IN operator be more useful for this expression?

Comment: @JohnDoee you can use `IN` operator if there is no wildcard usage `%`. `IN` will do exact matching only